# disable/able textbox onclick radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im sorry but i tried everything that's available in the internet but all "solutions" doesnt work.

if the radio button is clicked, the textbox under that radio button will be enabled.else disabled.

pls help me with this.when i click the radio button, the textbox is still disabled.

js

```
function radioModeOfPayment(x){
if(document.getElementById('mMininum').checked == true){
    document.getElementById("mMininum-amount").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("first").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("numMonth-months").disabled = true;
}
if(document.getElementById('numMonth').checked == true){
    document.getElementById("numMonth-months").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("mMininum-amount").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("first").disabled = true;
}
}
```

html

```
<div class="trbl-padding-5">
    <input type="radio" class="w3-radio" id="mMininum" name="mpayment" value="mMininum" onclick="radioModeOfPayment(this);">    <label class="w3-validate">Minimum Payment</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly="true" value="Amount">   <input type="text" class="tlabel w3-border" disabled="disabled" id="mMininum-amount" name="mMininum-amount" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly="true" value="Starting Date">    <input type="date" disabled="disabled" id="first" name="sdate"><br>
</div>
<div class="trbl-padding-5">
    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" id="numMonth" name="mpayment" value="numMonth" onclick="radioModeOfPayment(this);">    <label class="w3-validate">Number of Months</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly="true" value="Months">       <input type="text" class="tlabel w3-border" readonly="true" id="numMonth-months" name="numMonth-months" value=""><br>
</div>
```

Comment: your code works fine (sort of) - what exactly is your problem

Comment: It is working fine fine Check [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/80us04em/)

Comment: really?
the textbox wont be "able". once i click the radio button

Comment: remove the `readonly="true"` from `numMonth-months` and try.

Comment: i remove the readonly part.but still the same

Comment: @phloxangrex try check my answer

Answer (score 1):

remove input text readonly  attribute

```js
function radioModeOfPayment(x) {
  if (document.getElementById('mMininum').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("mMininum-amount").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("first").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("numMonth-months").disabled = true;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('numMonth').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("numMonth-months").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("mMininum-amount").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("first").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="trbl-padding-5">
  <input type="radio" class="w3-radio" id="mMininum" name="mpayment" value="mMininum" onclick="radioModeOfPayment(this);">
  <label class="w3-validate">Minimum Payment</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly="true" value="Amount">
  <input type="text" class="tlabel w3-border" disabled="disabled" id="mMininum-amount" name="mMininum-amount" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly="true" value="Starting Date">
  <input type="date" disabled="disabled" id="first" name="sdate">
  <br>
</div>
<div class="trbl-padding-5">
  <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" id="numMonth" name="mpayment" value="numMonth" onclick="radioModeOfPayment(this);">
  <label class="w3-validate">Number of Months</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly="true" value="Months">
  <input type="text" class="tlabel w3-border"  id="numMonth-months" name="numMonth-months" value="">
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: when you click radio button in Number of Months ? are you able to write text there or not ??

Comment: @phloxangrex but in my snippet can't you able to write ?

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT 2

In Snippet 2 it is exactly the same as OP's layout. By adding [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), the inputs on the right-side are the only inputs that are enabled and disabled while the ones on the left are unaffected. The attribute `disabled` and have been removed.

#### EDIT

Sorry forgot OP wants radio buttons, it works just as well.
Here's a simple CSS only solution.

This uses:

1. [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)
2. [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

#### SNIPPET 1

```css
.chx:checked + input {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.chxs:checked ~ input {
  pointer-events: none
}
input[name="rad"]:checked + input[type="text"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p>This example uses + which affects only the sibling that's immediately after .chx</p>
<input class='chx' type='checkbox'>
<input>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>This example uses ~ which affects all siblings that follow .chxs</p>
<input class='chxs' type='checkbox'>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>Works on radio buttons as well</p>
<fieldset>
  <input name='rad' type='radio'>
  <input type='text'>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input name='rad' type='radio'>
  <input type='text'>
</fieldset>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```css
.w3-radio:checked ~ input:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="trbl-padding-5">

  <input type="radio" class="w3-radio" id="mMininum" name="mpayment" value="mMininum">

  <label class="w3-validate">Minimum Payment</label>

  <br>

  <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly=true value="Amount">

  <input type="text" class="tlabel w3-border" id="mMininum-amount" name="mMininum-amount" value="">

  <br>

  <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly=true value="Starting Date">

  <input type="date" id="first" name="sdate">

  <br>

</div>

<div class="trbl-padding-5">

  <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" id="numMonth" name="mpayment" value="numMonth">

  <label class="w3-validate">Number of Months</label>

  <br>

  <input type="text" class="tlabel" readonly=true value="Months">

  <input type="text" class="tlabel w3-border" id="numMonth-months" name="numMonth-months" value="">

  <br>

</div>
```